# Docker-compose backup mongoDB of a rocketchat server

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, rocket.chat, mongorestore

#### Description

this is an issue that I really don't understand what's causing it

first, I created a backup of the mongo using the following command:

```
docker exec db sh -c "mongodump --archive" > db.dump
```

to make sure this is working, i deleted the containers I already had, then ran a new mongo container, and restored the mongoDB using:

```
docker exec -i bd sh -c "mongorestore --archive" < db.dump
```

and it worked, when opening rocket chat all the messages, the custom settings are still the same.

the problem is when moving to docker-compose, this doesn't seem to work the same way. I created three containers of Mongo, one for the main DB, one that initializes the replica sets, and the third one restores the data into the first one, the docker-compose file is looks like this:

```
services:
  #this is the main mongo database that rocket chat container will be communicating with
  db:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mongo:4.4
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --oplogSize 128 --replSet rs0
    container_name: db
  # this container's job is just run the command to initialize the replica set. it will run the command and remove himself
  mongo-init-replica:
    image: mongo:4.4
    volumes:
      - ./db.dump:/db.dump:chmod=600
      - ./init-replica.sh:/init-replica.sh
    command: /init-replica.sh
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: mongo-init-replica
  # container that restores the data from a db.dump file
  mongo-restore:
    image: mongo:4.4
    volumes:
      - ./db.dump:/db.dump:chmod=600
      - ./mongo-restore.sh:/mongo-restore.sh
    command: /mongo-restore.sh
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: mongo-restore
    # this container is the rocket chat container that uses the mongo service as its mongo database
  rocketchat:
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: rocketchat
    image: rocket.chat:5.2.0
    volumes:
      - ./rocket-chat.sh:/rocket-chat.sh
    command: /rocket-chat.sh
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - ROOT_URL=https://localhost
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://db:27017/rocketchat?replicaSet=rs0&directConnection=true
      - MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://db:27017/local?replicaSet=rs0&directConnection=true
```

as per the scripts involved, they look something like this :

**init-replica.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Loop for 20 times
for i in $(seq 1 20); do
    # Initialize MongoDB replica set
    mongo db/rocketchat --eval 'rs.initiate({ _id: "rs0", members: [ { _id: 0, host: "localhost:27017" } ]})'
    s=$?
    # If successful, break out of the loop
    if [ $s -eq 0 ]; then
        break
    else
        echo "Tried $i times. Waiting 5 secs..."
        sleep 5
    fi
done

# exit container
exit $s
```

**mongo-restore.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Sleep for 10 seconds, then restore MongoDB from dump
echo 'waiting for database to be initialized'
sleep 10

# Mongo restore data into our mongo container
mongorestore --archive=/db.dump --host db

# Store the exit status of mongorestore command
s=$?

# Stop container and exit
exit $s
```

**rocket-chat.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Sleep for 30 seconds
echo 'rocket chat waiting to start'
sleep 30

# Loop for 30 times
for i in $(seq 1 30); do
    # Run main.js using node
    node main.js
    s=$?
    # If successful, break out of the loop
    if [ $s -eq 0 ]; then
        break
    else
        echo "Tried $i times. Waiting 5 secs..."
        sleep 5
    fi
done

# Exit with the status code of the last executed command
exit $s
```

when running `docker-compose up`, the logs of *mongo-restore* show that the operation was successful (as the following image shows), however when launching rocket chat, it takes me to the initial wizard setup, with all the configurations back to the default ones. it basically behaves as if there is no data in the mongo containers, but i double-checked that there is

[image: logs of mongo-resotre service]

#### rocket chat server info

[image: rocket chat server info]